# Como pegar os parâmetros de uma closure em php

Tags: php, html

Como eu poderia pegar os parâmentros de uma closure?
Eu estava fazendo uns testes e dei um `var_dump` em uma closure e ela me retornou isso

```
object(Closure)#5 (1) {
  ["parameter"]=> 
    array(2) {
    ["$val"]=>
    string(10) ""
    ["$val2"]=>
    string(10) ""
  }
}
```

E me surgiu a dúvida, como eu acesso o array `'paramenter'`?

```
var_dump("<pre>", function($val, $val2){ });
```

Comment: se pode colocar o código completo?

Comment: ```var_dump("<pre>", function($val, $val2){
});```

Comment: coloca o código na pergunta editando a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar os parâmetros de um função anônima pode ser feito com [ReflectionFunction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php), ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

$fs = function($val, $val2){ return $val + $val2; };

$reflection = new ReflectionFunction($fs);
$arguments  = $reflection->getParameters();
var_dump($arguments);
```

e em sua saída do comando `var_dump`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(ReflectionParameter)#3 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "val"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(ReflectionParameter)#4 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "val2"
  }
}
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Deducing PHP Closure parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198804/deducing-php-closure-parameters)</sup>